# lightbox not working on new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, lightbox

Hy, I'm having some problems making lightbox (in my case slimbox 2) work
after new content is loaded. I understand that slimbox needs to be called again, but I tried almost everything.
Here is the code how new content is been loaded:

```
...var link = $('<a class="loadpost" href="javascript:">Load more</a>');
link.click(loadMore);...
```

loadMore is the function that loads new content. this is just a piece of code. if you need the whole code let me  know.

Here is the slimbox code.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
});
```

the new content has the rel attributes but it wont work. can i combine the click function from above to call slimbox code again.

Answer (score 0):

Long version:

Without more of the code (if you can, make a jsfiddle or something similar) it's hard to know if this is the only issue, but one immediate issue I'm seeing is that you're using jQuery's $(" ") wrong. You're supposed to put a selector in there, so that jQuery can find whatever it is you want it to find in the DOM; what you're feeding it is a string of HTML.

Browsers use HTML to make the DOM (Document Object Model) tree, which you can think of as an abstracted logic tree of your HTML; the DOM sees 'a.loadpost' as a *parent* of the text node inside of it (in this case, 'Load more'). CSS and Javascript/jQuery both find information from that abstracted logic tree in pretty similar ways. With a few exceptions, if you know how to target something with CSS, you know how to target it with jQuery -- just select whatever HTML you need to select the same way you would with CSS.

So, to tell jQuery to do something to a link with a class of 'loadpost', you simply write $('a.loadpost'). $("a.loadpost") works as well.

Short version:

```
var link = $('a.loadmore');
```